# How do I extend the nonce life in the Public Post Preview plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, preview, nonce

I'd like to extend the length of the URL preview duration in the 'Public Post Preview' Wordpress plugin.

The default for an unpublished post via a generated link is 48 hours. I have seen the suggested code on Stack Overflow to extend the duration (example below is 7 days).

My question is: where do I amend the filter value from 48 hours? Which exact file do I need and where is it located?

I'm not a developer but would be accessing files via FTP and doing it myself so so step-by-step would be really helpful. Thanks in advance for any advice, it's something I've been meaning to do for literally years!

```
add_filter( 'ppp_nonce_life', 'my_nonce_life' );
function my_nonce_life() {
    return 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // 7 days
}
```

Comment: It seem you already have all the code you need for this, all that's left to do is to actually add it to your site: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-to-paste-ppp_nonce_life-code/

Comment: Thanks @cabrerahector - I will remind myself of FTP and amend the file. Guess I'll know if it's worked if a preview link lasts more than the standard 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code into the functions.php file that you will find in the folder that contains your active WordPress theme.

For example if your theme is called "Super Theme", browse to your wp-content/themes folder and find the folder for your active theme, probably called something like super-theme. In there, you'll find many files, including one called functions.php.

Open that file and pop the code into it. You can add it right at the start or at end, but make sure you put it after the opening <?php tag which is normally right at the top of that file.